# How can I fix it:Model doesn't work at pose mode

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4

Like the following image I cannot combine bones at my model:

[image: image1]

I just used armature-human(meta rig) but it seems doesn't work.
When I imported it to UE4, I couldn't apply motions to my model.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect armature with the skin (model). Here is the easiest way:

1. select your model in object mode
2. shift select your armature in object mode
3. set parent to / with automatic weights (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)

This will add armature modifier to your model and automaticaly create weights for each bone as vertex groups. Also it will set armature as parent of the model.